# How to convert R output from auto.arima function into mathematical model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm building a model using the `auto.arima` function in R, and it gives the following output:

```r
arima(x = revtrend, order = c(2, 1, 2))
Coefficients:
   ar1     ar2     ma1      ma2
1.1894 -0.1975  0.4387  -0.5613
```

Can someone help me write this as an actual mathematical model? I believe I'm getting a bit lost in the notation. Thank you!

Comment: See [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+equation) (you may need to narrow down the search further by adding terms like "output", "auto.arima" or other).

Answer (score 1):

Let $B(.)$ denote the backshift operator, i.e. $B y_t = y_{t-1}$. Then we can write a general non-seasonal ARIMA(p, d, q) as

$$
\underbrace{(1 - \phi_1 B - ... - \phi_p B^p)}_{\text{AR(p)}} \ \underbrace{(1-B)^d}_{\text{d differences}} \ y_t 
  = \underbrace{(1+\theta_1 B + ... + \theta_q B^q) \epsilon_t}_{\text{MA(q)}}
$$

and $\epsilon_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0, \sigma)$

You just need to substitute the parameter estimates in with $p=2, d=1, q=2$. If you want to remove the backshift operator, simply expand everything out and notice that $B^k y_t = y_{t-k}$